# flex-items space is not being distributed in small screen

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have trying to add `justify-content: space-between;` so both flex elements have equal space between.

- Notice the red `div`, inside both items are 'stuck' together no space
  between in `320px` screen with size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgfAa.jpg
- Again, in `856px` screen with, no space is being distributed,
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HXjw.jpg
- Now in `1364px` screen with space is being distributed, [http://imgur.com/a/05tsj](https://imgur.com/a/05tsj)

I am trying to get space distributed using `justify-content: space-between;`

Any ideas?

```css
/* SECTION THREE */
.sec-3 {
  background-color: #f1eeee;
  margin-top: -22px;
}

.sec-3-flex {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.sec-3-flex #iphone-2-img {
  padding-top: 30px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin-right: -10%;
}

.sec-3-flex .sales-copy-wrap {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#iphone-sec-3 {}
```

```html
<div class="sec-3">
  <!-- iphone image  -->
  <div class="sec-3-flex">
    <!-- Iphone 1 image -->
    <picture id="iphone-sec-3">
      <!-- <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img/mobile/mobile-iphone-1.jpg"> -->
      <source media="(min-width: 320px)" srcset="img/desktop/images/home_11.jpg">
      <img id="iphone-2-img" src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:50%">
    </picture>
    <div class="sales-copy-wrap">
      <h3>Get organized with events, tasks and notes.</h3>
      <p class="sales-copy">Now more then ever it is critical for smart professionals to stay up to date with important deadlines.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In the above CSS you are using justify-content: space-around;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is not a flex item. It is a child of a flex item (`picture`).

So inside this flex item the image is (naturally) aligned to the left.

Add this to your code:

```
picture {
   text-align: right;
}
```